# Get a message from swiftmailer about registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use fosUserBundle for registration. I want after the registration send email message about success. My config.yml looks like.

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: Games\ModelBundle\Entity\Users
  registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
        from_email:
            address:  registration@trololo.com
            sender_name:   Registration
  service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
  resetting:
    email:
        template: CoreBundle:Email:resetting.email.html.twig

swiftmailer:
  transport: "%mailer_transport%"
  host:      "%mailer_host%"
  username:  "%mailer_user%"
  password:  "%mailer_password%"
  spool:     { type: memory }
```

My question is: How to check if message was sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you first want to test this locally if the code works as intended. Try to look into the "Profiler" after successfully registering, it should hold the emails.

Or if you write a functional test for it, this should help you get the idea:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html